# How to display image in div with its source

Tags: jquery

I am getting the image source from an li element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.k-state-selected').live("click", function () {
        var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        alert(src);
    });
});
```

So how can i display image in a another div using its source?

Comment: Please note that `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, which is quite a long time... you should use `on()` or even the shortcut `click()` method instead. and maybe look into event delagation if you need to attach handlers to dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.k-state-selected').live("click", function () {
        var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        $("#youOtherDiv").append("<img src='"+ src + "' />");
    });
});
```

Just add a new line ;) like this

Comment: But append will add images in a div one by one  when you click on other images. so better to choose html in place of append to show one image at a time when we clicked on a image.

Comment: depends on your requirements ;)

Answer (score 4):

Like this - please note that `live` is deprecated:

```
$(function () {
    $('li.k-state-selected').on("click", function () {
        var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        $("#someDivId").html('<img/>', {"src":src, "alt":"My Image"});
    });
});
```

or just

```
$(function () {
    $('li.k-state-selected').on("click", function () {
        var $img = $(this).find("img").clone();
        $("#someDivId").append($img);
    });
});
```

If the LI's are dynamically added, you might want to delegate:

```
$(function () {
    $("#someStaticParentContainer").on("click", "li.k-state-selected",function () {
        $("#someDivId").append($(this).find("img").clone());
    });
});
```

Comment: *side note:* remember that `alt` attribute is required for `<img>` tag for HTML standards.

Comment: I think you should also mention delegated events in your answer as `live()` was somehow working also on "future" (= dynamically created) elements

Comment: You are welcome. Any particular reason you chose to accept the other less complete answer?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this in your click event:

```
$(this).find("img").clone().appendTo(".container-to-add-to");
```